# How to turn a one file program into an .exe in Monodevelop on a Mac

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I am a c# programming beginner. I have a small one file program that I would like to package up as an .exe. I am using Monodevelop on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Just build it in MonoDevelop.  Then use the output of the build in bin/debug or bin/release.  That is your executable.